# ZodError on the start of a docker image

Tags: typescript, docker, web, zod

i'm new on the web developement and i got a huge code.
I tried to run it locally and it work fine but when i try to build the image and run it, it show me a ZodError

```
ZodError: [
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "undefined",
    "path": [
      "serverUrl"
    ],
    "message": "Required"
  }
]
```

My dockerfile look like this:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g pnpm --unsafe-perm

COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./

RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile --prefer-offline

COPY . .

RUN pnpm build \
    && pnpm build:server \
        && pnpm install --prod --frozen-lockfile --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline --reporter=silent

FROM node:16-alpine

RUN apk add --update --no-cache curl

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG release

ENV RELEASE=$staging
ENV NODE_ENV=staging
ENV PORT=80

EXPOSE 80

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/node_modules node_modules
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/server/dist .
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/src/.next src/.next
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/src/public/static src/public/static
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/src/next.config.js src

CMD ["node", "./server/index.js"]
```

I tried to modify my .env file and put a backend_url or a host but nothing works.
I searched every where on the internet but find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I was just not using right my ENV varibles, when i run my docker image i have to put my ENV varables with it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).